# How to I add a column to a table, that combines strings from other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concatenation, alter

I am using Mysql Browser.

I have a table called "users". I am looking to create a column called, "opp". I know how to do this, with a simple Alter Table, Add statement. Where I am struggling is figuring out how to add data to the column. I want the column to be a combination of strings using concat().

The column should end looking like:

"Team(name)" where name is data from a column titled "name" in the table "users".

I have tried a Insert into statement like this:

Insert Into users (opp)
VALUES ('Team', '(', name, ')')

But that did not work. It tells me there is no such column as "name", even though there is...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have altered  the table you should use an UPDATE

```
update  users 
set opp = concat( 'team(',name ,')' )
;
```

anyway  column like this should not be store  ..  because you can obatin this with  simply

```
select  concat( 'team(',name ,')' ) opp from user
```

Comment: Maybe he meant that the column name needs to be concated it is not very clear what the topicstarter meant..

Comment: @RaymondNijland  . may  be  ..  i see you ahve already asked for a sample  ..

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great @JordanFreundlich that you found you answer can you next time add a data example in your question.. Like "required" by the stackoverflow [helpdesk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines ?   As that would also help stopping poeple from willing to voteclose your question as unclear

Answer (score 0):

Why bother adding a column?  You can use a view:

```
select u.*, concat('team('name , ')') as opp
from u;
```

Comment: Not sure about the theory, again new to databases. But It is a db of sports teams. There is an opponent column in a table that looks like "Team(name)", so I figured I needed to create an id code for all the teams, so that I can run some analysis on matchup data.